# want to make an asynchronous function that stores data from a sql database in an array

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am currently working on a node backend and would like to store data asynchronously from a sql database. In the first step I store the data from the database in an array and in the second step I want to output the array in the console. The problem is that the array is empty every time I output it outside the fetchProducts function. When I output the array inside the function, the entries are correct.

How can I make the function asynchronous so that the console output is only made after all entries in the array have been saved?

```
let products = [];

async function fetchProducts () {

    
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1`,(err, row) => {
        let maxId = row.id;

        for(let i=1; i<=maxId; i++){
            db.get(`SELECT * FROM products where id = '${i}'`,(err, row)=>{
                let product = {
                    id: row.id,
                    name: row.name,
                    describtion: row.describtion,
                    price: row.price
                };
                products.push(product);

            });
        }
   
    })     
}

async function start (){
    await fetchProducts()
    console.log(products);
}

start();
```

Comment: Why do you need to do extra SELECTs at all?  Your first query gets all the information you need for the array.

Comment: I did it because I wanted the max id for the counter. Im sure it´s not the best solution. But my problem is to async console.log the array

Comment: You need to `await` the `db.get()` calls